# My checkbox is not pre-filled with value present in redux state i.e true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> I am trying to implement tick on value set to true and no tick on
> value set to false from redux state but checkbox is always set to tick
> on server start. My onchange handler is also working fine and
> console.log is also displaying correct values.

My code is as follow-

```
const TaskItem = ({tasks:{task,_id,date,checkbox},deleteTodo,loading}) => {
const [formData,setformData]=useState({
    checkbox1:{checkbox}
})

const {checkbox1}=formData;
console.log(checkbox1);
const onChange=e=>{
    setformData({...formData,[e.target.name]:e.target.checked})
}

    return (
        <div className="list">
        <p>
        
        <Moment style={{backgroundColor:"rgba(27,112,137)", border:"1px"}}
        format='YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm a'>
        
        {date}
        
        
        </Moment>
        <br/>
        <input
            name="checkbox1"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checkbox1}
            onChange={e=>onChange(e)}

       
    

            />
        
    
        {task}
        
        <span>
        
        
        <i className="fas fa-trash" onClick={()=>{deleteTodo(_id)}}></i>
        
        </span>
        </p>
        
            
        </div>
        
    )
}

TaskItem.propTypes = {
    tasks:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    deleteTodo:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    


}

export default connect(null,{deleteTodo}) (TaskItem)
```

[image: Below is my homepage and console]

[image: Below is my homepage and redux state]

Comment: try removing this: 
`checked={checkbox1}` from your `<input>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [formData,setformData]=useState({
    checkbox1:{checkbox}
})
```

is equivalent to:

```
const [formData,setformData]=useState({
    checkbox1:{checkbox: checkbox}
})
```

so `<input checked={checkbox1} />` is like : `<input checked={{checkbox: false}} />` at start, so the checkbox will be checked. (since `{checkbox: false}` is `truthy`.)

so based on the type of `checkbox` redux state, change it. if it's a true/false value, change your code to :

```
const [formData,setformData]=useState({
    checkbox1: checkbox
})
```

if it's a object and has a checked property, change it to: `checkbox1: checkbox.ischecked`